# elasticsearch with RSS plugin hangs after restart

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have a clean ES server on my mac with the RSS plugin - after adding several sources the server hangs after I restart it (because I wanted to add additional plugins or restarting the mac).

Is there a way to prevent it / restore the current installation?

Log:

> [2015-01-14 09:43:27,870][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast]
>   [Mar-Vell] received ping response ping_response{node
>   [[Asmodeus][JpUdhq0FRYKr7RqDqcK7WQ][Dorons-MBP.Home][inet[/10.0.0.7:9300]]],
>   id[1089], master
>   [[Asmodeus][JpUdhq0FRYKr7RqDqcK7WQ][Dorons-MBP.Home][inet[/10.0.0.7:9300]]],
>   hasJoinedOnce [true], cluster_name[elasticsearch]} with no matching id
>   [2] [2015-01-14 09:43:30,724][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.health]
>   [Mar-Vell] no known master node, scheduling a retry [2015-01-14
>   09:43:57,943][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [Mar-Vell] failed to
>   connect to master
>   [[Asmodeus][JpUdhq0FRYKr7RqDqcK7WQ][Dorons-MBP.Home][inet[/10.0.0.7:9300]]],
>   retrying... org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException:
>   [Asmodeus][inet[/10.0.0.7:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:807)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:741)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:714)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:150)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.joinElectedMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:441)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:393)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$6000(ZenDiscovery.java:80)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException:
>   connection timed out: /10.0.0.7:9300  at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:139)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>     ... 3 more [2015-01-14
>   09:44:00,729][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.health] [Mar-Vell] observer:
>   timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time
>   since start [30s] [2015-01-14 09:44:01,048][WARN
>   ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Mar-Vell] received ping response
>   ping_response{node
>   [[Asmodeus][JpUdhq0FRYKr7RqDqcK7WQ][Dorons-MBP.Home][inet[/10.0.0.7:9300]]],
>   id[1095], master
>   [[Asmodeus][JpUdhq0FRYKr7RqDqcK7WQ][Dorons-MBP.Home][inet[/10.0.0.7:9300]]],
>   hasJoinedOnce [true], cluster_name[elasticsearch]} with no matching id
>   [3]